# Blackberry ESS standalone mode & Outlook 2007

Tags: blackberry, outlook-2007, ess

I launch Blackberry ESS in standalone mode. However I don't have Outlook Express on my computer. Instead I have Outlook 2007 on my computer. I set up an email account in Outlook 2007 which uses 'localhost' as its pop3/smtp server. The port numbers I used are the same as those in http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/5590-sending-receiving-email-device-simulator.html. However I got the following exception. 'UnknownHostException:pop3.server'. I am wondering if Outlook 2007 works with ESS.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the issue. I forgot to fill the following fields.

Name

The name to display in outgoing messages from the device simulator

Email

The email address to display in outgoing messages from the device simulator

But it is quite weird that the error message is UnknowHostException.